# Add document if query returns 0 documents

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to add a document to a collection if a query that I run returns no results. I placed the query below but there are no operators for checking the length or the size of the resulting query. How can I do this?

Here is the query:

```
this.monthCollection = this.afs.collection('users').doc(this.auth.getUserId()).collection('months', ref => {
  return ref.where('endTimestamp', '>=', moment().unix()).limit(1);
});
```

If that query does not return any documents then I need to run `createNewMonth();` to add to the months collection. Here is the createNewMonth` method

```
createNewMonth() {
    let date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
    let firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

    let newMonth = {
      categories: [],
      endTimestamp: moment(lastDay).unix(),
      name: this.getMonthNameFromTimestamp(moment().unix()),
      startTimestamp: moment(firstDay).unix(),
      totalSpent: 0
    }
    return this.monthCollection.add(newMonth);
  }
```

Is there a way I can do this inside the query if I use `.then()` or does it need to be outside the query?

EDIT: So I found a way for it to create one but it creates 2 every time instead of just one. Here is the code.

```
this.currentMonth = this.monthCollection.snapshotChanges().map(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.length <= 0) {
        this.createNewMonth();   <---- here is what I added, it creates 2
      }

      return snapshot.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.payload.doc.data();
        data.id = doc.payload.doc.id;
        this.currentMonthId = doc.payload.doc.id;
        this.currentMonthTotalSpent = doc.payload.doc.data().totalSpent;

        this.expenseCollection = this.monthCollection.doc(doc.payload.doc.id).collection('expenses');
        this.expenses = this.expenseCollection.snapshotChanges().map(snapshot => {
          return snapshot.map(doc => {
            const data = doc.payload.doc.data();
            data.id = doc.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          });
        });
        return data;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

In angularfire2 when running `.snapshotChanges()` you can check if results were found like this:

```
this.dbRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(doc => {

if(doc.payload.exists)
{
///Do something with the returned data
}
else
{
this.createNewMonth();
}

});
```

when looking for `.valueChanges()` if no data was found then 'doc' will be returned as null:

```
this.dbRef.valueChanges().subscribe(doc => {

if(doc)
{
///Do something with the returned data
}
else
{
this.createNewMonth();
}

});
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work with how I am getting the months could you please write this in the context of the example code?